# How to extract a value from an XML node?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string as follows:

```
xmlString=@"<product><name>abc</name><price>9.8</price></product>";
```

I want to extract the value of price and assign it to a variable `Price`:

```
double Price = ???
```

How do I do so given the xmlString?

Comment: XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Element("price").Value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var product = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
var price = (decimal)product.Element("price");
```

Comment: I wish you'd waited until he spent some effort before handing him the answer. Look at his other questions - he already knows about LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
string xmlString = @"<product><name>abc</name><price>9.8</price></product>";
XmlDataDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlString);

XmlNodeList list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("product/price");

foreach (XmlNode n in list)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(n.ChildNodes[0].Value);
  }
```